# Modify a specific column for an Item when another column is modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate

For an Item in my list I have three columns, "date started", "date completed", and "# of business days to complete"

Is there a way to build a flow so that when "date completed" is modified it calculates the number of business days between the two dates (including holidays) and auto fills the "# of business days to complete" column?

I have a list that stores the holidays for reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to your needs, I suggest that you can create a Calculated column to achieve your needs.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Go to the list, click **List settings**

[image]

2.On the List Settings page, under the **Columns** section, click "**Create column**" to create a Calculated column named [# of business days to complete]

[image]

3.Please use the below the Formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Completed]),"",([Date Completed]-[Date Started]))
```

[image]

4.Here is my test:

[image]

Comment: thank you, I have tried this and this doesnt take into account holidays though. From my understanding the only way I can do that is using flow and referring to my other holiday list somehow.

Comment: Hi FatZack. According to my understanding, you want to calculate the number of working days between [Date Started] and [Date Completed], and you want to exclude holidays. Can you upload screenshots of the Holiday list? This will help us solve the problem better.

Comment: just uploaded it.

Comment: Hi FatZack. Sorry, I still can’t see any information you uploaded here (including screenshots)

Comment: for some reason it was deleted by admin, but it is a simple list with two columns. One is the Holiday date and one is the Holidays name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are testing it, and we will respond promptly as soon as there is any result